# How to access the native search button of a browser using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, webautomation

I was trying to search for a url: `https://rewards.bing.com/pointsbreakdown` with the help of Selenium in Python so I wrote the following block of code

```
search_in_first = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sb_form_q')
search_in_first.send_keys(search_random_word())
search_in_first.submit()
```

but it redirects to a new google/bing search webpage [Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpIpU.png)
insted of [Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4iRg.png). So I want to know how to get hold of the inbuilt search box in my python script.

I tried the following code block

```
search_in_first = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sb_form_q')
search_in_first.send_keys(search_random_word())
search_in_first.submit()
```

to get hold of the search box but it doesn't work well and search in this box.

Inner search box:

[image: Inner search box]

instead of this:

[image: Outer search box]

Comment: Is this problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the link, then you need to use. `driver get(url)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time 


options = Options() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\yourusername\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")
driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service, options=options)

# Define the search keyword
keyword = "hello"

driver.get(f"https://www.bing.com/search?q={keyword}")

time. Sleep(10) # Wait for 10 seconds
```

Comment: thank you but the code didn't work for the Microsoft Edge browser rather it is for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

here you GO :) this work for Microsoft Edge browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
import time

options = Options()

driver_service = Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=driver_service, options=options)

# Define the search keyword
keyword = "hello"

driver.get(f"https://www.bing.com/search?q={keyword}")

time.sleep(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use the search box for URL navigation in Microsoft Edge, which is not possible. URLs you put into the Bing search box will turn into search results.

The correct way for URL navigation should be using `driver.get()` for the URL.